# Credit Card Charges for Foreign Purchases

Tags: canada, credit

I used my Mastercard when purchasing on vacation in Canada.  When I received my credit card bill, I did see the Foreign Fee attached, which was fine.

However, in my most recent activity, I found the credit card company charged the difference between my US dollar purchases and Canadian dollars purchases, which resulted in an additional $35 in payment for those purchases (on my Bank Account). It appears Canada was not "honoring" the exchange rate and would not pay the credit card company the difference between the two dollar amounts; i.e., I paid $19.99 for a bottle of wine (canadian money) and was charged initially $15+ on my credit card - which would explain the exchange rate.  However, on my September 8th Recent Activity statement, it appeared Canada did not "honor" that exchange - only paying the credit card company the $15+ instead of the $19.99.  Because of that, the Credit Card Company charged me the difference as uncollected funds?!  This not only happened with each of my purchases on my vacation in Canada this past August, but also on a genealogy site for the Drouin Site for one day.  The cost was $5 for the day; my credit card was charged $4.40.  However, the credit card company again charged me the difference from Canadian Monies ($5-$4.40) so I owed the additional $.60!?

Why is this?  Each of the transactions I saw, all had foreign fees, wasn't that enough!?  I don't understand?!

Janet R. Haley

Comment: This is not something that Canada (the country, or its government) is doing to you, it's purely controlled by your agreement with the card issuer.  Mastercard does currency conversion (which directly affects what you pay) and collects some processing fees (but the merchant pays these).

Comment: This doesn't sound right, you should probably call the credit card company and ask for explanation.